# How do I add uibutton.configuration to button created in IB?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uistackview

I'm trying to update my app buttons with `UIButton.configuration`. This works fine if I create the button in code, following a YouTube tutorial:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createButton()

    }
    
    func createButton(){
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        button.center = view.center
        button.configuration = createConfig()
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
        
    func createConfig() -> UIButton.Configuration {
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        config.baseBackgroundColor = .systemRed
        config.image = UIImage (named: "binoculars")
        config.cornerStyle = .large
        config.titleAlignment = .center
        return config
    }
}
```

Problem is that my buttons are already existing, having been created in IB, and are embedded in `StackViews`. I've tried specifying the (IB created) button via an `IBOutlet`, but that doesn't seem to work. I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what. I really don't want to create a `StackView` and position the buttons in code if I can avoid it...

All help appreciated!
TIA!

**Edit:**
My error here was declaring my IBOutlet within the ViewDidLoad method. Once I removed the reference outside, everything worked fine! Here is the revised code, which, Im sure will work within my UIStackViews, as shown in DonMag's answer below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.configuration = createConfig()
    }
        
    func createConfig() -> UIButton.Configuration {
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        config.baseBackgroundColor = .systemRed
        config.image = UIImage (named: "binoculars")
        config.cornerStyle = .large
        config.titleAlignment = .center

        return config
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? Is it to have a `UIButton` outlet and then have your code still create and set the button configuration (on the outlet) or are you asking how to setup the configuration in IB and have no code at all for the button or its configuration?

Comment: @HangarRash — I want to create and position the buttons in a uistackview in IB, then create the UIButton.configuration and set it on the button in code (as shown in my question).

Comment: Please update your question showing your attempt to do so. Clearly explain what issues you are having with that attempt.

Comment: Please see edit above!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have added buttons in IB, you don't want to create new buttons.

Connect them via `@IBOutlet` and then ***apply your configuration*** in code.

So, in IB / Storyboard... two buttons with `Style: Plain` in a vertical stack view:

[image]

```
class DynamicButtonConfigVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var btn1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btn2: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        btn1.configuration = createConfig()
        btn2.configuration = createConfig()
        
    }
    
    func createConfig() -> UIButton.Configuration {
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        config.baseBackgroundColor = .systemRed
        // I don't have your "binoculars" asset image, so
        //  using SF Symbols image
        config.image = UIImage (systemName: "binoculars")
        config.cornerStyle = .large
        config.titleAlignment = .center
        return config
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]